# FTP Shell Script Not Working

Tags: linux, shell, ftp

Ok, So I am trying to ftp some recording files to remote a server for backup every night. I am very confused regarding shell script. 
My question / problem is : I want to move to remote a server the whole folder/directory instead of FILE. Where am I wrong?

Here is current script:

```
HOST='10.113.68.50'
USER='sms'
PASSWD='Abc123451'
LOCALPATH='kmpy/unica/Campaign/partitions/partition1/CiktiDosyalari'
FILE=*.sms
DIR='SMS/'

ftp -n $HOST <<EOF
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
cd $DIR
lcd $LOCALPATH
put $FILE
quit
exit;
EOF
```

Comment: In case the shown Ip is none you made up I would change it for your security.

Comment: @ben: address is `private class A IP` and will not be routed over the internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it that you only receive one file?  For 'ftp' to use file globbing you need to use the 'mput' command.  Replace `put $FILE` with:

```
prompt
mput $FILE
```

You need the 'prompt' command to turn off interactivity, and 'mput' will put multiple files.

However, 'ftp' might not be the best tool for the job.  I would recommend using 'rsync'.  The task above can be done with:

```
HOST='10.113.68.50'
USER='sms'
RSYNC_PASSWORD='Abc123451'
LOCALPATH='kmpy/unica/Campaign/partitions/partition1/CiktiDosyalari'
FILE=*.sms
DIR='SMS/'

rsync -avz $(LOCALPATH)/$(FILE) $(USER)@$(HOST):$(DIR)
```

'rsync' will only transfer the changes in the files and compress the transfer.

EDIT: Typically 'rsync' uses 'ssh' by default for authentication.  If you want to use the 'rsh' method (which is the same as for 'ftp') you should do something like:

```
rsync -avz --rsh=rsh $(LOCALPATH)/$(FILE) $(USER)@$(HOST):$(DIR)
```

Answer (score 0):

The ftp `put` command can only be used with a single file.  If your `*.sms` expands to more than that, it will copy the first file across, and give it the name of the second file in your list.
You should use the `mput` command instead, or `tar` everything into one archive, transfer that, and then untar it at the other end.